# How I can monitor the output files and move/rename in desired directory

Tags: c++, bash, ubuntu

A program generates a text file after every 15 iterations. It overwrites the `output.txt` (formed at 15th step) with a new `output.txt` (formed at 30th step), due to using the same name. I can't modify the file name within the program. Can I run some script concurrently with the program on my Ubuntu system that monitors my directory and moves the `output.txt` file to a desired directory when it is formed or changes the output file name?

Comment: sorry for inconvenience. I added if there is a way through programming.

Comment: Since you mention [tag:c++] and [tag:ubuntu], you can write a program using the [tag:inotify] interface provided by Linux. I am not aware of any [tag:bash] interface to [tag:inotify].

Comment: Ah, wait, there is [tag:inotifywait] from the `inotify-tools` package.

Comment: Since I am beginner user in c++. However thank you for the hint! I am looking into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can't modify the file name within the program.

(I take this to mean you are required to not change the file name, not that you don't know how.)

You've marked this posting as C++.

While it is possible to run some script to monitor a directory, coordinating the name change and running a thread or another process (from C++) can be much more challenging than other choices.

How about a simpler approach:

I suggest using std::stringstream to generate a unique pfn (path-file-name) for each time you want to write a file.  For instance, an incrementing number can be appended to the unmodifiable-file-name.

Something like:

```
std::string uniqueFileName(void)
{
   std::stringstream ss;

   //     vvvvvvvvvv -- unmodifiable-file-name is not changed
   ss << "output.txt" << ++fileCount; 

   uniqueFileName = ss.str();

   return(uniqueFileName);
}
```

Good luck.

---

PS

If you feel you must write the file first in the correct file name, and then change the file name to something unique ... yes, you can rename the file from within this program (i.e. trivial synchronization)

I would use popen() as I feel it provides more feedback, and I've used it before.

Others prefer something like system() (there are about 6 of these).

In either case, use the command to rename the existing file (to each you provide a bash command, like mv fromPfn toPfn, or maybe you'll need cp.

For each, your code must not proceed until the command has completed.

Comment: Today I see I typo'd the return value (it matches the function name, and should be different)  and I forgot to declare it (as a string).  So, one fix would be to replace the last 2 lines in the function with return(ss.str()).